# Can't retrieve data with AJAX from Bootstrap tabs generated with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

So i have a select box which triggers an AJAX call to retrieve information from MYSQL which displays Bootstrap tabs. I'm trying to do another call to AJAX to display content in every tabs based of their value but can't seem to get a result back.

Here is part of the code that generates the tabs:

```
$result= $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
echo"
<div id=\"tabs\">
    <ul class=\"nav nav-tabs\">";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo"
        <li class=\"nav-item\">
        <a class=\"nav-link\" id=\"gruppo\" value=\"".$row["id_gruppo"]."\" data-toggle=\"tab\" href=\"#".$row["id_gruppo"]."\">".$row["nome_gruppo"]."</a>
        <div id=\"show1\"></div>
        </li>";
      }
    echo"</ul></div>";
}
```

This is the AJAX code that i came with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#gruppo").change(function(){ 
      var id_gruppo = $(this).val(); 
      var dataString = "id_gruppo="+id_gruppo; 

      $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST",
        url: "getData.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(result){
          $("#show1").html(result);
        }
      });

    });
  });
</script>
```

And just to test if anything happens this is the code of the page getData.php

```
 if(!empty($_POST["id_gruppo"]))
 {
  $id_gruppo=$_POST["id_gruppo"];
  echo"Gruppo:".$id_gruppo;
 }
```

Comment: You need to look in the browser console, firstly for errors & then at the networking tab to check the request is sent and to see what is received in the response.

Comment: Change `var id_gruppo = $(this).val();` to `var id_gruppo = $(this).attr("value");`. Because an `a` does not have a `.val()`

Comment: @peeebeee They are created in php not dynamically

Comment: @AlexK. i've tried that and it seems that the actual request is not sent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Mabrouki Fakhri i found the solution.

function that gets called for every tab:

```
<script>
   function GetDataFromDB(id_gruppo){
        $.ajax({ /* THEN THE AJAX CALL */
            type: "POST", /* TYPE OF METHOD TO USE TO PASS THE DATA */
            url: "getData.php", /* PAGE WHERE WE WILL PASS THE DATA */
            data: "id_gruppo="+id_gruppo, /* THE DATA WE WILL BE PASSING */
            success: function(result1){ /* GET THE TO BE RETURNED DATA */
            $("#home").html(result1); /* THE RETURNED DATA WILL BE SHOWN IN THIS DIV */
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

code that generatates every tab:

```
  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        echo"
        <div id=\"tabs\">
            <ul class=\"nav nav-tabs\">";
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo"
                <li class=\"nav-item\">
                    <a class=\"nav-link\" id=\"gruppo\" onclick=\"GetDataFromDB(".$row["id_gruppo"].");\" value=\"".$row["id_gruppo"]."\" data-toggle=\"tab\" href=\"#".$row["id_gruppo"]."\">".$row["nome_gruppo"]."</a>
                </li>";
      }
            echo"
                </ul>
            </div>";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same ID for multiple tags so the event won't be trigged :

```
... <a class=\"nav-link\" id=\"gruppo\"> ...
```

Try this : First define your function like this :

```
function doThisOnChange(id){ 
  var id_gruppo = id; 
  var dataString = "id_gruppo="+id_gruppo; 

  $.ajax({ 
    type: "POST",
    url: "getData.php",
    data: dataString,
    success: function(result){
      $("#show1").html(result);
    }
  });

}
```

Then your PHP part become :

```
...
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo"
            <li class=\"nav-item\">
                <a class=\"nav-link\" id=\"gruppo-".$row["id_gruppo"]."\" value=\"".$row["id_gruppo"]."\" onChange=\"doThisOnChange(".$row["id_gruppo"].") \"
data-toggle=\"tab\" href=\"#".$row["id_gruppo"]."\">".$row["nome_gruppo"]."</a>
                <div id=\"show1\"></div>
            </li>";
  }

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because bootstrap does not know that a new `tab` element has come in. Enable the tab by calling the `tab('show)`

```
.ajax({ 
    type: "POST",
    url: "getData.php",
    data: dataString,
    success: function(result){
      $("#show1").html(result);
      $('.nav-item).tab('show');
    }
});
```